# Local in show ip bgp output

Tags: cisco, bgp

What does Local mean in this output?

```
R4#show ip bgp 10.6.0.0/24  
BGP routing table entry for 10.6.0.0/24, version 19  
Paths: (1 available, best #1, table Default-IP-Routing-Table)  
  Advertised to update-groups:  
        2  
  **Local**    192.168.0.6 (metric 156160) from 192.168.0.5 (192.168.0.5)  
      Origin IGP, metric 0, localpref 100, valid, internal, best  
      Originator: 192.168.0.6, Cluster list: 192.168.0.5
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

The `Local` keyword highlighted in your question means the prefix is sourced locally in that router's AS (i.e. there is no AS path).

Consider two configurations, where the routers have a BGP session with each other, and `DEN-EDGE-01` is announcing 10.204.1.1/32.

```
Announce:10.204.1.1/32
DEN-EDGE-01----------------DEN-EDGE-02
172.16.1.203               172.16.1.204
```

#### Peering within the same ASN: `Local` keyword shown

`DEN-EDGE-01` in AS100 is configured to send 10.204.1.1...

```
router bgp 100
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 10.204.1.1 mask 255.255.255.255
 ! Send 10.204.1.1 to DEN-EDGE-02
 neighbor 172.16.2.204 remote-as 100
 no auto-summary
```

`DEN-EDGE-02` in AS100 is configured with...

```
router bgp 100
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 ! Just receive routes from DEN-EDGE-01
 neighbor 172.16.2.203 remote-as 100
 no auto-summary
!
```

When I receive 10.204.1.1 on `DEN-EDGE-02`, there is no AS-path, only **`Local`**

```
DEN-EDGE-02#sh ip bgp 10.204.1.1
BGP routing table entry for 10.204.1.1/32, version 2
Paths: (1 available, best #1, table Default-IP-Routing-Table)
Flag: 0x820
  Not advertised to any peer
  Local   <------------
    172.16.2.203 from 172.16.2.203 (172.16.2.203)
      Origin IGP, metric 0, localpref 100, valid, internal, best
DEN-EDGE-02#
```

#### Peering with a different ASN: AS path shown

Now we reconfigure both routers... one in AS100 and the other in AS200.  `DEN-EDGE-01` in AS100 is configured to send 10.204.1.1...

```
router bgp 100
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 10.204.1.1 mask 255.255.255.255
 ! Send 10.204.1.1 to DEN-EDGE-02
 neighbor 172.16.2.204 remote-as 200
 no auto-summary
```

`DEN-EDGE-02` in AS200 is configured with...

```
router bgp 200
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 ! Just receive routes from DEN-EDGE-01
 neighbor 172.16.2.203 remote-as 100
 no auto-summary
!
```

When I receive 10.204.1.1 on `DEN-EDGE-02`, now we see a real AS-path, because `DEN-EDGE-01` is in a different AS.

```
DEN-EDGE-02#sh ip bgp 10.204.1.1
BGP routing table entry for 10.204.1.1/32, version 2
Paths: (1 available, best #1, table Default-IP-Routing-Table)
Flag: 0x820
  Not advertised to any peer
  100   <------------
    172.16.2.203 from 172.16.2.203 (172.16.2.203)
      Origin IGP, metric 0, localpref 100, valid, external, best
DEN-EDGE-02#
```

Comment: @kashish you're most welcome. If your questions are answered,  please consider [accepting the answer that was helpful to you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160519)